# Animating expanding gradient pattern on object

Tags: animation, node-editor, color

I'm attempting to create an animation of an expanding gradient area on a simple beam.

I managed to do this with a single color as shown below by applying keyframes to a ColorRamp in the node editor.

[image]

[image]

However I wish to have the top plane of the beam have a red color that gradually turns blue when going near the bottom side of the beam as pictured below (rough draft made in photoshop below to illustrate what im after if my explanation was confusing).

[image]

Is there a simple way to do this in Blender 2.91? I have played around in the node editor for a while but can't come up with any solutions on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want both effects at once, or just the top to bottom?

Answer (score 6):

You could do it this way: Create an *Input > Texture Coordinate* node, a *Vector > Mapping* node, a *Converter > Serpate XYZ* node, use a *Color > MixRGB* node to mix a red and blue gradient with a grey color, and use a b&w *ColorRamp* as a factor to create the horizontal gradient. To take Marty's comment into account, if you want the color borders to be sharp, use the *Constant* option instead of *Linear* in the ColorRamp.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want the edges of the red/blue to bleed into the gray area, use [moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots)' approach, but if you want the edges to be sharp here's an alternative:

[image: alternate version]

In this version you animate the threshold value of the Greater Than math node. At 0, the beam is entirely red/blue. At .5 it is entirely whatever you put in Color2.

This approach can give you blurred edges if you replace the Greater Than node with a color ramp.  In this case, animate the left handle of the color ramp for the width:

[image: variation on original]